# How to draw round dot stroke pattern for a CAShapeLayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, cashapelayer

I am trying to stroke the paths in `CAShapeLayer` using dash patterns. I have created many dash patterns using `lineDashPattern` property. But this property doesn't give any option for type of dash stroked. I want to be my dashes to be round dots like in image below:

[image]

I know it can be achieved because I have seen this in many apps. But I am not able to find any way to implement this in `CAShapeLayer` library. So I want to know how to get these round dot dash pattern?

Answer (score 8):

All you have to do is to set ***kCALineCapRound*** for the **lineCap** property of your CAShapeLayer and then set your ***lineDashPattern*** to [0.0, x ], where for example x is 2 * the line width of your CAShapelayer if you want the margin between the dots to be as long as your dots diameter.

The 0.0 for the first painted segment in ***lineDashPattern*** is there cause ***kCALineCapRound*** draws a semicircle in front of and behind your painted segment and any painted segment bigger than zero would cause the dot to become a pill.[image]

Comment: Even if i set `x = 2 * linewitdh` it gives me pills

Comment: X has nothing to do with the form of the dot, it defines the margin between the dots (the unpainted segment). The Zero in the example is what the dot forms, if the painted segment is bigger than zero it gives you a pill.

Answer (score 5):

try //swift

```
layer.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
layer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
layer.lineWidth = 4
layer.lineDashPattern = [0.01, layer.lineWidth * 2]
layer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below snippet

```
shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2 * stroke.width()], nil];
shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;
```